# laravel trying to get property of non-object when i type php artisan serve

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I have seeded a admin user and overrided postRegister() method.

I logged in with the credentials with which I have seeded.

After logging in I tried to register calling auth/register.

```
    @extends('master')

@section('title','Creating.. User')

@section('content')
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    @if (count($errors) > 0)
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                            <ul>
                                @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                    <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                                @endforeach
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/create') }}">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Mobile</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="mobile">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Team</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="team_id">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!--
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Role</label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="role">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        -->
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Register
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Now,i tried to register after logging in as admin.I did this to create users.

This is my routes.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth']],function(){
    if(auth()->user()->id==1){
        Route::get('/create',function(){
            return view('create');
        });
        //Route::post('/create','Auth/AuthController@create');
    }
    else{
        echo "You are not permitted to create user";
    }
});
Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);
```

This is my postRegister method in Auth\AuthController :

```
public function postRegister(Request $request){

    $user = new User();
    $user->name = ucwords($request->input('name'));
    $user->email = strtolower($request->input('email'));
    $user->mobile = $request->input('mobile');
    $user->team_id = $request->input('team_id');
    $user->password = Hash::make($request->input('password'));

    $user->save();

    return "yes";
}
```

After doing this I got an error and then I tried to restart the server with php artisan serve.Now,I am getting an error exception when i run command as.

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\mpms>php artisan serve
```

> 

[ErrorException] Trying to get property of non-object

Comment: I made a mistake.I came to know that auth()->guest() will help for it.

Comment: what's the error line number

Comment: Routes.php line-2 .If should be added inside create.I don't know the logic but it worked for me.I get another error now if I try to create a user after logging error is displayed as "method not allowed".can anyone tell me.How to create a user after logging in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax of route:group is

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', function ()    {
        // Uses Auth Middleware
    });
});
```

And to create a user after login add this route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'],function(){

        Route::get('/create',function() {
            return view('create');
        });
});
```

the form should post data to

```
action="{{ url('/auth/register') }}
```

Comment: I have overrided the method auth/register.I created an admin and admin can create users.I cannot call the post/register method directly.So,I created a new method to store users..